# Can I obtain intuit oauth access token and secret with desktop app?

Tags: oauth, delphi-xe2, intuit-partner-platform

We have a **desktop** app (Delphi XE2) that gets an oauth request token from Intuit and fires off the URL call to Intuit where the user authorizes our app. This half of the oauth dance seems to be working.

The problem we are running into is getting the **Access Token** and **Access Token Secret**. We never seem to get it.

Details:

This is for QuickBooks v3 API.

We have a web service setup to handle the callback whose URL we pass along when we make the call to get with request token to https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin

That opens the Intuit web page with our test company and our app listed. When we grant access to our app from the Intuit site the web browser is redirected to our callback URL and that contains an oauth token (which I'm not really sure is our access token) but we never get the access **secret**. That's the missing thing for us.

Is the token we are getting in the callback our access token?

If so how do we get the access secret? Is that token another token to be used to make another call to https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token where we would obtain our access token and secret?

I tried using the token returned to our callback URL as a token for the "get access token" url and that gave me unauthorized errors.

If the token returned to our callback URL is not the access token where/how the heck do we get it?

Any help or direction is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

So, it turns out I was missing one entire step of the OAuth dance.

After the user authorizes access and that passes the original request token and a verifier key to our web service. That verifier key is used with the original token in yet another call to Intuit to get the access token and access token secret.

Cheers!
TJ

Comment: I started on QB v3 API access with Delphi, then got pulled into another project for a bit. ([I commented on your other question about it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738305/delphi-xe2-always-getting-401-unauthorized-trying-to-get-oauth-access-token)) But I should be back to it in a couple weeks...any chance you could email me some code (mrw (at) goflagship.com)? After getting it working here, I'd promise to try to get an article written on accessing QB Online via Delphi (sharing attribution with you), for the benefit of the Delphi community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial callback returns to you a request token, which you then have to send back to Intuit via the `get_access_token` URL to get an access token and secret.

Intuit instructions:
[Implement OAuth in Your App](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/implement_oauth_in_your_app)

The OAuth spec it refers to is [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I realized I was missing an entire step of the OAuth dance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the sample V3 APP.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java

To be specific, please refer

[OAuthController.java](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/blob/master/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/java/com/intuit/controller/support/OAuthController.java) and [OAuthHelper.java](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/blob/master/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/java/com/intuit/utils/OauthHelper.java)

Thanks